# Running db-sync via CLI

Tags: cardano-db-sync

While running the `db-sync` what to pass as a parameters is unclear.

```
PGPASSFILE=config/pgpass-mainnet cabal run cardano-db-sync -- \
    --config config/mainnet-config.yaml \
    --socket-path /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/node.socket \
    --state-dir /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/ledger \
    --schema-dir schema/ \
    --disable-ledger
```

1. What should I pass to `--state-dir`? I did pass ledger folder where my node stores data.
2. I'm going to subscribe blocks to read information such as from & to addresses, amount etc. If I pass `--disable-ledger` would it be a problem?
3. While running `db-sync` I'd like to pass the latest snapshot in here how do I pass it? (https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/index.html#13/)
4. How do I pass port which `db-sync` runs? When I was running it via docker it was `3100` by default.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> What should I pass to --state-dir? I did pass ledger folder where my node stores data.

This should not be the same as any directory the `node` uses. Its for `db-sync` and related programs only.

> I'm going to subscribe blocks to read information such as from & to addresses, amount etc. If I pass --disable-ledger would it be a problem?

This is documented. `--disable-ledger` means you will get all on-chain data but you don't get reward payments from the reward account associated with each address (until after they have been withdrawn), you don't get the epoch stake distribution and a couple of other minor things.

> While running db-sync I'd like to pass the latest snapshot in here how do I pass it?

Its [documented](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/state-snapshot.md). You make sure `db-sync` is not running, restore the snapshot, then you run `db-sync`.

> How do I pass port which db-sync runs?

Port for what? The PostgreSQL port for accessing the database? That is set by the PostgreSQL configuration.